# Showing that the Cayley Transform is an involution.

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

For a finite dimensional vector space V the Cayley Transform is a function $T: Gl(V) \to End(V)$ such that $T(f) = (I-f)(I+f)^{-1}$. I am asked to show that the Cayley Transformation is an involution, which means that $T(T(f)) = f$. I tried to do this by evaluating the function and I get that $T(T(f)) = (I-(I-f)(1+f)^{-1})(I+(I-f)(I+f)^{-1})^{-1}$, I don't really know what to do from here.

Comment: As $-I\in GL(V)$, I dare ask: What is $T(-I)$?

Comment: This is just a matter of standard manipulation of fractions, because you are working inside a **commutative** subalgebra of $\operatorname{End}\left(V\right)$ (namely, the subalgebra generated by $f$).

Comment: Also note that there are problems with the claim in characteristic 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Caveat Emptor:*** $T(f)$ is clearly *not* defined on all of $GL(V)$, since there are clearly going to be problems when $f$ has $-1$ as an eigenvalue, forcing $\not \exists (I + f)^{-1}$; as Hagen vonn Eitzen asked, "what is $T(-I)$?"  Nevertheless, when $T(f)$ *is* defined, using the commutativity of all operators involved, we may compute:

$T(f) = (I - f)(I + f)^{-1}; \tag 1$

$T(T(f)) = (I- T(f))(I + T(f))^{-1}; \tag 2$

$T(T(f)) = (I - (I - f)(I + f)^{-1})(I + (I - f)(I + f)^{-1})^{-1}; \tag 3$

$TT(f)) = (I + f)^{-1}((I + f) - (I - f))(I + (I - f)(I + f)^{-1})^{-1}$
$ = (I + f)^{-1}(2f)(I + (I - f)(I + f)^{-1})^{-1} = 2f((I + f) + (I + f)(I - f)(I + f)^{-1})^{-1}$
$= 2f((I + f) + (I - f))^{-1} = (2f)(2I)^{-1} = f, \tag 4$

$OE\Delta.$

***Nota Bene:*** And of course I assumed we are not in characteristic $2$! ***End of Note.***